# How to use multiple dynamic routes in next js 13

Tags: reactjs, next.js, routes

I'm working on a project where there'll be guides, and within each guide there'll be chapters.

The structure is as follows:

[App structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRI6B.png)

And I have the chapters files within their own folder as you can see:

[Guide structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Covy7.png)

Now, to render the chapter's content I need to use the `guideSlug` and the `chapterSlug` in the same file.

I'm used to using single dynamic route with next js 13, but I'm yet to find a folution to this in the next js 13 documentation.

I tried doing it using `generateStaticParams` following the docs example with no success.